# publish asp.net mvc5 without installing visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Finally, i have completed my asp.net mvc5 project.

I have used EF code first  for database and my solution included two part, the core included Model and frontend included the views and the controller.

Now i want to send the project to my friend that he can publish it in his windows server with **IIS server**.

My question is  which file i have to copy for him that he can publish the WebApp with out installing visual studio in his windows server.

[image: The main's file look like that]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on main MVC project in your solution -> **Publish**.

Publish method: **File System**

Target location: your location

In settings Configuration you can set **Release** or **Debug** as you need.

After publish you can send whole folder to your friend. Everything that you need should be there (Your bins, views, scripts, css).

Your friend should just create new WebSite in IIS and place all files in folder that he selected.

Ofcourse he should change connection strings and set right settings for `ApplocationPool` that runnig WebSite.

Comment: That was helpful.. and then i have to attach the database as sql script right ?

Comment: @John you said you use EF with code first. If you've done everything right then on site start application should create db if you don't have it. But if not then you should sent script - right. Also you can send backup or even create [Database Project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/825831/sql-server-database-development-in-visual-studio) and send `.dacpac` file that your friend can use to create and then migrate your db. I prefer last option, but i don't use code first.

Comment: Every thing going well now except App Pool i didn't got it.many thanks ::

Comment: @John app pool wa introduced in [IIS 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dbaa793-0a05-4914-a065-4d109db3b910). So if you don't have it - it's ok.